# Error when trying to deploy OSGi bundle containing Servlet on Domino server

Tags: servlets, osgi, lotus-domino

I am trying to deploy an OSGi bundle on a Domino server. The bundle contains a servlet and static web resources. The resources and the servlet are registered using the *org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources* and *org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.servlets* extension points. The bundle is copied to the applications/eclipse/... folder below domino/data.

When I enter the alias to the static resources I get the requested page. This page in turn makes a request to the servlet but gets a 500 return code. The server console shows **HTTP Web Server: Command Not Handled Exception**

In the error log there is a message **java.lang.ClassCastException: mypackage.SimpleServlet incompatible with javax.servlet.Servlet**

The SimpleServlet is simply a class which implements javax.servlet.Servlet.

Can anyone say why this might be happening? What can I do to get more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have multiple copies of the Servlet API hanging around. You need to find out if there are multiple bundles exporting the `javax.servlet` package, and make sure that both the HTTP server bundle (which is part of Domino, presumably) and your own bundle import it from the same place.